# Can I use facebook javascript SDK on a embedded macheine with Private IP?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, embedded, private

I have some problems with Facebook Javascript SDK.

I want to write some html and javascript codes to upload photos to FB,

and these codes are implemented on my machine, this machine is a embedded board,

so the IP address is private IP.I cannot run Apache on this board, and I don't want to

leave my App Secret in the source code.So I think using JS SDK would be a possible way.

But a serious problem comes presently, in my APP settings , I can't use IP address as APP domain, nor a private IP.

Is it possbile to use Facebook Javascript SDK on a embedded board with private IP adderss ?

When I run those codes on my linux PC (also with private IP), the debug message shows that my domain is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you have some hosts-file equivalent where you can point some subdomain of the domain associated with the app to the private IP.

For example, if the domain associated with the app is `example.com` and the IP of the device is `1.2.3.4`, if you somehow make DNS lookups for `example.com` resolve to `1.2.3.4` then access the site via `example.com`, this will work. You can also use any subdomain of the main domain.